# Having trouble understanding moving items from a list to an empty list

Tags: python

In the below sample code I'm not understanding why in my sent_message() I get output from smsg but not txt_msgs[0]  Also not understanding why my sent_msg list remains empty?

```
txt_msgs = ['Mr Johnson, your new Cornwell Banks credit card is waiting for you at 13 High Street.', 'Boarding for your flight 320-YBO starts 12.11.2018 at 3:30pm. Enjoy your flight, Fair Airlines.', 'Booking confirmation: 4445789-YY. Millington Hotel is expecting you on 22.12.2018. Thank you for your order!']

sent_msg = []

def show_messages(txt_msgs):
    for msg in txt_msgs:
        print(f"\n{msg}")

def sent_messages(txt_msgs):
    for msg in txt_msgs:
        smsg = txt_msgs.pop()
        sent_msg.append(smsg)
        print(f"\n{smsg}")
        
#print(txt_msgs)
print(sent_msg)
#show_messages(txt_msgs)
sent_messages(txt_msgs)
```

Here's the output I get:

```
 []

Booking confirmation: 4445789-YY. Millington Hotel is expecting you on 22.12.2018. Thank you for your order!

Boarding for your flight 320-YBO starts 12.11.2018 at 3:30pm. Enjoy your flight, Fair Airlines.
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sent_msg = []
txt_msgs= ["Hey"]
def show_messages(txt_msgs):
    for msg in txt_msgs:
        print(f"\n{msg}")

def sent_messages(txt_msgs):
    for msg in txt_msgs:
        smsg = txt_msgs.pop()
        sent_msg.append(smsg)
        print(f"\n{smsg}")
        
        
#print(txt_msgs)
#Here it's empty 
print(sent_msg)
#show_messages(txt_msgs)
sent_messages(txt_msgs)
#Here the message is append to the list
print(sent_msg)
```

***The problem is you printed sent_msg before anything was append to the it thus the list was empty***

Comment: These changes did make some improvement, however I thought the for loop would print all the messages in txt_msgs but it only printing the last message.  I still don't understand why but when I uncomment out show_messages() that function print all 3 messages  I expected the pop function to pop all 3 messages and append all 3

Comment: Once I removed the return sent_msg I got the output I was expecting

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your print sentmsg is called before the actual method call which adds data to the list.